# using "being" instead of "is"

Tags: meaning

I have come across a quatation  where "being" is used insted of "is" Here goes a part of it: "people are so anxious about the future that they do not enjoy the present; the result *being* that they do not live in the present or future." Should it be "the result is that..."?

Answer (score 3):

If you use "is", that is a new sentence. With "being", this becomes a non-finite clause modifying the first sentence.

Given that the text you quote sets it off with a semicolon, I would prefer "is": I would separate the form with "being" with just a comma. But niceties of punctuation are rather subjective.